# c++ when reading from a file i continualy get dirty memory in my array and in my file

Tags: c++, dirty-data

we were supposed to create a program that can memorize drugs data for a farmacy we were supposd to make 3 function 1 for searching using the code 2 to show the understock in alphabetical description order and 3 to save and load the memorized data from a file called "dati.txt" but we ran in a dirty data problem the program write dirty data or read dirty data i can't figure out if is the loading or the writing pls help me
ps i'm new to programming and i m still learnign

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

#define Num 300
int n = 0;
FILE* file;

struct s_farmaci {

    int codice;
    string descrizione;
    float prezzo;
    int disponibilita;
};

void bubblesort(s_farmaci vet[], int num);
void sottoscorta(s_farmaci vet[], int tanti);
int ricercabin(s_farmaci vet[], int inizio, int fine, int codice);
int menu();
void caricamento(s_farmaci farmaco[]);
void mostrafarmaco(s_farmaci farmaco[], int indice);
void scambia(s_farmaci v[], int i, int j);
void salvahdd(s_farmaci farmaco[]);
void caricahdd(s_farmaci farmaco[]);

int main()
{
    s_farmaci farmaco[Num];
    int scelta;
    int codicericerca;
    int trovato = -1;
    caricahdd(farmaco);
    system("pause");
    scelta = menu();
    do
    {
        switch (scelta) {
        case 4:
        {
            cout << "stai per uscire dal programma" << endl;
            salvahdd(farmaco);
            cout << "dati salvati correttamente correttamente" << endl;
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            caricamento(farmaco);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            bubblesort(farmaco, n);
            cout << "quale codice vuoi cercare? ";
            cin >> codicericerca;
            trovato = ricercabin(farmaco, 0, n - 1, codicericerca);
            if (trovato == -1)
                cout << "Prodotto non trovato!" << endl;
            else {
                cout << "prodotto trovato: " << endl;
                mostrafarmaco(farmaco, trovato);
            }
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            sottoscorta(farmaco, n);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            cout << " errore scelta non valida riprova " << endl;
            break;
        }
        }
        system("pause");
        scelta = menu();
    } while (scelta != 0);
    return 0;
}
//bubblesort of the code
void bubblesort(s_farmaci vet[], int num)
{
    int tempcodice;
    float tempprezzo;
    int tempquantita;
    string tempdescrizzione;
    bool scambi = false;
    do {
        scambi = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; i++) {
            if (vet[i].codice > vet[i + 1].codice) {
                scambi = true;

                tempcodice = vet[i].codice;
                vet[i].codice = vet[i + 1].codice;
                vet[i + 1].codice = tempcodice;

                tempprezzo = vet[i].prezzo;
                vet[i].prezzo = vet[i + 1].prezzo;
                vet[i + 1].prezzo = tempprezzo;

                tempquantita = vet[i].disponibilita;
                vet[i].disponibilita = vet[i + 1].disponibilita;
                vet[i + 1].disponibilita = tempcodice;

                tempdescrizzione = vet[i].descrizione;
                vet[i].descrizione = vet[i + 1].descrizione;
                vet[i + 1].descrizione = tempdescrizzione;
            }
        }
    } while (scambi == true);
}
//menu
int menu()
{
    system("cls");
    int scelta;

    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "-    BENVENUTI              -" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "-                           -" << endl;
    cout << "-    1 caricamento          -" << endl;
    cout << "-    2 ricerca              -" << endl;
    cout << "-    3 mostra               -" << endl;
    cout << "-    4 salva                -" << endl;
    cout << "-                           -" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;

    cout << "-- inserici numero: ";
    cin >> scelta;
    return scelta;
}
//get drugs information
void caricamento(s_farmaci farmaco[]) {
    system("cls");
    cout << "inserisci il " << n + 1 << " farmaco" << endl;
    //inserisco il codice
    cout << "insersci il codice: ";
    cin >> farmaco[n].codice;
    //inserisco la descrizione
    cout << "inserisci la descrizione del farmaco: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, farmaco[n].descrizione);
    //inserisco il prezzo
    cout << "inserici il prezzo: ";
    cin >> farmaco[n].prezzo;
    //inserico la disponibilita
    cout << "inserci quanti farmaci sono disponibili: ";
    cin >> farmaco[n].disponibilita;
    cout << endl;
    n++;

}
/show memorized drugs
void mostrafarmaco(s_farmaci farmaco[], int indice) {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "codice farmaco        :" << farmaco[indice].codice << endl;
    cout << "descrizione farmaco   :" << farmaco[indice].descrizione << endl;
    cout << "prezzo farmaco        :" << farmaco[indice].prezzo << endl;
    cout << "quantita disponibili :" << farmaco[indice].disponibilita << endl;
}
//binary search
int ricercabin(s_farmaci vet[], int inizio, int fine, int codice) {
    int medio;
    if (inizio > fine)
        return -1;
    else {
        medio = (inizio + fine) / 2;
        if (codice == vet[medio].codice)
            return medio;
        else
            if (codice > vet[medio].codice)
                return ricercabin(vet, medio + 1, fine, codice);
            else
                return ricercabin(vet, inizio, medio - 1, codice);
    }
}
//show me understock
void sottoscorta(s_farmaci vet[], int tanti) {
    int tempcodice;
    float tempprezzo;
    int tempquantita;
    for (int x = 0; x < tanti; x++) {

        //algoritmo di ordinamento
        int i, j;
        string temp;

        //sorting farmacs description       
        for (j = 0; j < tanti - 1; j++)
            for (i = 0; i < tanti - 1; i++)
                if (vet[i].descrizione > vet[i+1].descrizione)
                    scambia(vet, i, i+1);
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < tanti; k++) {
        if (vet[k].disponibilita < 3) {
            cout << endl;
            cout << " il codice del farmaco e':" << vet[k].codice << endl;
            cout << " la descrizione del farmaco e':" << vet[k].descrizione << endl;
            cout << " il prezzo del farmaco e':" << vet[k].prezzo << endl;
            cout << " la disponibilita' del farmaco e':" << vet[k].disponibilita << endl;
        }
    }
}
//exchange variables
void scambia(s_farmaci v[], int i, int j) {
    s_farmaci temp;
    temp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = temp;
}
//get file from hdd
void caricahdd(s_farmaci farmaco[]) {
    n = 0;
    if ((file = fopen("dati.txt", "rb")) == NULL)
        cout << "errore apertura file" << endl;
    else {
        while (!feof(file)) {
            fread(&farmaco[n], sizeof(s_farmaci), 1, file);
            n++;
        }
        fclose(file);
        cout << "dati caricati correttamente" << endl;
    }
}
//save file on hdd
void salvahdd(s_farmaci farmaco[]) {
    if ((file = fopen("dati.txt", "wb")) == NULL)
        cout << "errore apertura file" << endl;
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            fwrite(&farmaco[i], sizeof(s_farmaci), 1, file);
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you mixing C and C++ io? C and C++ are difficult on their own, mixing them for no reason is unecessary complexity

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: thank you i was using c because on my book and my professor told me to do so and to use that command if u can help and change the command I would realy appreciate

Comment: You can't write and read `std::string` instances to files in that manner. You *could* read up about serialization, but I suspect that you are actually supposed to use a fixed-size array of `char`.

Answer (score 0):

You say read-file get dirty data in array;
But it's not dirty data

```
fread(&farmaco[n], sizeof(s_farmaci), 1, file);
```

It only means that, read some data and put in the address(&farmaco[n]).But C++ don't know how to correctly set the data for the member of the array.

For Example:

```
/*this is the data file*/
19     /*set age value*/
Hello  /*set name value*/
20     /*set age value*/
Exam   /*set name value*/
```

And a struct has two members

```
struct people
{
  int age;
  string name;
}
```

The array people[2],this is how to read data and set value

```
/*read the first data and set people[0].age*/
people[0].age = 19
/*read the second data and set people[0].name*/
people[0].name= Hello
/*read the third data and set people[1].age*/
people[1].age = 19
/*read the fourth data and set people[1].name*/
people[1].name= Hello
/*and so on*/
```

Comment: You may should read file and set value for the member of the array

Comment: I m Sorry can you explain Better or show me some example i don't understand what you mean

Comment: I have edit my commit with a example